# Exporting private key from Bitcoin Core to claim my BCH on Exodus

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-cash

My BTC is currently in a Bitcoin Core wallet and this is where I want to keep my BTC.

I'm trying to claim my BCH, while using Exodus as the wallet.

However, when I try to "move" my funds via ***Exodus > Developer > Assets > Bitcoin Cash > Move Funds (WIF)...*** by entering my private key, I get an error that states "Invalid network version".

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Mine doesn't say 'Move Funds (WIF)' it says 'Move Funds' and it works fine. Are you using the most recent version of Exodus?

Comment: Oh, I note that you have it sorted, "i talked to somebody via email support and they walked me thru it.", @Anthony - you can help by closing this question so that it does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

Hi there have you tried these steps?

How do I claim Bitcoin Cash?

UPDATE:

As of OCTOBER 12, 2017, Bitcoin Cash has been enabled in Exodus 1.36.0 so you can now send Bitcoin Cash to Exodus. To download the latest version, please go here:

http://support.exodus.io/article/27-how-do-i-upgrade-exodus

Below are the instructions on how to claim Bitcoin Cash if you had Bitcoin on July 31st, 2017.

Important: This will not work unless you are updated to the latest version of Exodus.

To claim your Bitcoin Cash inside of Exodus click on the help section then scroll all the way to the bottom of the help section to find the section titled; "How Do I claim my Bitcoin Cash." When you open that help section you will see a green button to start the process on claiming your Bitcoin Cash.

Step 1: Click on the Help button on the left side of Exodus. (Scroll down for Step 2)

Step 2: Scroll all the way to the bottom of the help section and find the help article titled "How do I claim my Bitcoin Cash?" - Click on that to expand it. (Scroll down for Step 3)

Step 3: Read the text to tell you a little about the process then click the green button to begin to claim your Bitcoin Cash. (Scroll down for Step 4)

Step 4: Exodus tells you the process is starting and gives you some information and a warning to be sure you are sending your Bitcoin Cash to a trusted source. Click the Blue Continue button. (Scroll down for Step 5)

Step 5: Exodus now asks you for your Bitcoin Cash address to know where you want your Bitcoin Cash sent. If you're updated to Exodus 1.36.0, you can now acquire your own Bitcoin Cash address. Feel free to input your Exodus BCH address to send it there or send it to any other Bitcoin Cash wallet of your choice. (Scroll down for Step 6)

Step 6: Exodus will now check your wallet and count up all your available Bitcoin Cash to send out. Depending on how many transactions you have - this process takes about 10 minutes. Click the blue "Check My Wallet Now" button to begin. (Scroll down for Step 7)

Step 7: Exodus now tells you the total amount of Bitcoin Cash you have to send out and also gives you the network mining fee this transaction will cost to send out. Because Bitcoin Cash blocks today are a bit slower this transaction could take 1-2 hours to confirm. If everything looks good click the red "Send" button. (Scroll down for Step 8)

Step 8: Your Bitcoin Cash has been sent! You can click on the blue "View TX" button to monitor the status of your transaction. Remember Bitcoin Cash today can take 1-2 hours to confirm so be patient while you monitor your receiving address.

How do I claim Bitcoin Cash?

UPDATE:

As of OCTOBER 12, 2017, Bitcoin Cash has been enabled in Exodus 1.36.0 so you can now send Bitcoin Cash to Exodus. To download the latest version, please go here:

http://support.exodus.io/article/27-how-do-i-upgrade-exodus

Below are the instructions on how to claim Bitcoin Cash if you had Bitcoin on July 31st, 2017.

Important: This will not work unless you are updated to the latest version of Exodus.

To claim your Bitcoin Cash inside of Exodus click on the help section then scroll all the way to the bottom of the help section to find the section titled; "How Do I claim my Bitcoin Cash." When you open that help section you will see a green button to start the process on claiming your Bitcoin Cash.

Step 1: Click on the Help button on the left side of Exodus. (Scroll down for Step 2)

Step 2: Scroll all the way to the bottom of the help section and find the help article titled "How do I claim my Bitcoin Cash?" - Click on that to expand it. (Scroll down for Step 3)

Step 3: Read the text to tell you a little about the process then click the green button to begin to claim your Bitcoin Cash. (Scroll down for Step 4)

Step 4: Exodus tells you the process is starting and gives you some information and a warning to be sure you are sending your Bitcoin Cash to a trusted source. Click the Blue Continue button. (Scroll down for Step 5)

Step 5: Exodus now asks you for your Bitcoin Cash address to know where you want your Bitcoin Cash sent. If you're updated to Exodus 1.36.0, you can now acquire your own Bitcoin Cash address. Feel free to input your Exodus BCH address to send it there or send it to any other Bitcoin Cash wallet of your choice. (Scroll down for Step 6)

Step 6: Exodus will now check your wallet and count up all your available Bitcoin Cash to send out. Depending on how many transactions you have - this process takes about 10 minutes. Click the blue "Check My Wallet Now" button to begin. (Scroll down for Step 7)

Step 7: Exodus now tells you the total amount of Bitcoin Cash you have to send out and also gives you the network mining fee this transaction will cost to send out. Because Bitcoin Cash blocks today are a bit slower this transaction could take 1-2 hours to confirm. If everything looks good click the red "Send" button. (Scroll down for Step 8)

Step 8: Your Bitcoin Cash has been sent! You can click on the blue "View TX" button to monitor the status of your transaction. Remember Bitcoin Cash today can take 1-2 hours to confirm so be patient while you monitor your receiving address.

Comment: Try to visit http://support.exodus.io/article/64-how-do-i-claim-bitcoin-cash for a more detailed explanation

Comment: For a more detailed explanation visit http://support.exodus.io/article/64-how-do-i-claim-bitcoin-cash        hope it helps have a great day bye

Comment: i've already come across both of those articles. neither is relevant to my situation...